# Is there a way to specify a range of files for Python to loop over in a given directory?

Tags: python, file, file-conversion

I have a script that was iterating over files in a directory to convert them from one format to another. Unfortunately, I did not take into consideration the possibility of losing the connection to the network drive where the files reside, thus terminating my script. In the event of an error and as a way to keep track of how far into the directory the script was, I did have the program display to me the last file it read in. I would like to begin at the file where the script stopped instead of starting all the way back at the beginning.

Below is my original script. This script converts from DBF format to CSV.

```
import os
from dbfread import DBF
import pandas as pd

directory = 'Directory containing files'

for file in os.listdir(directory):

        if file.startswith('File_Prefix') and file.endswith('.DBF'):
            file_path = os.path.join(directory, file)
            print(f'\nReading in {file}...')
            dbf = DBF(file_path)
            dbf.encoding = 'utf-8'
            dbf.char_decode_errors = 'ignore'
            print('\nConverting to DataFrame...')
            df = pd.DataFrame(iter(dbf))
            df.columns.astype(str)
            print(df)
            print('\nWriting to CSV...')
            dest_directory = 'Destination_Directory\\%s.csv' % (File_Prefix + file.strip('.DBF'))
            df.to_csv(dest_directory, index = False)
            print(f'\nConverted {file} to CSV. Moving to next file...')

        elif file.startswith(Another_File_Prefix) and file.endswith('.DBF'):
            print('File not needed.')
            continue
        elif file.endswith('.FPT'):
            print('Skipping FPT file.')
            continue

        elif file.startswith('Another_file_prefix') and file.endswith('.DB~'):
            print('All files converted to CSV.')
            break

        else:
            print('\nFile not found or error.')
            print(f'Last file read in was {file}.')
```

What could I modify to specify the last file read in and start from there while ignoring the previous converted files? The names of the files in the directory are rather vague, just a letter and a number that increases as you travel down through the directory (e.g. 'A0001.DBF', 'A0002.DBF', 'A0003.DBF', etc.)

My initial solution was to assign the last file to a variable and then modify my "if" statement.

```
start_file = last_file_read_in

for file in os.listdir(directory):
    if file == start_file:
       #run conversion code
       #continue iterating through each file starting from this point
```

Comment: You could peek inside the destination directory for already converted files and insert a conditional to only convert if the converted file is not present.

Comment: @snnguyen Thanks for your resppnse. I forgot about `os.path.exists(path)`. Logically though, how could I write that out so that the script first checks the destination directory to see if a file has already been convererted, and if not, to read in the unconverted file from the original directory?

Comment: Since the filenames are not renamed and only differ by file ending, put all filenames in your destination directory into a set. If the filename is not in the set, convert it otherwise you skip.